# How to connect my SQL query to my reset button in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm setting up a bunch of code and now I've got a problem. I've made a pageview counter on my basic website. I already made a query function to store it, now I'll want to make a button to reset it to 0. Only I don't know how to do it.

I already tried to some code like but this is not working:

```
<a class="action" href="<?php reset_visits($page);?>" target="_blank">Reset visits</a>
```

This is my query function I already made:

```
  global $db;

  $errors = validate_page($page);
  if(!empty($errors)) {
    return $errors;
  }

  $sql = "UPDATE pages SET ";
  $sql .= "pageviews = 0 ";
  $sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $page['id']) . "' ";
  $sql .= "LIMIT 1";

  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  // For UPDATE statements, $result is true/false
  if($result) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // UPDATE failed
    echo mysqli_error($db);
    db_disconnect($db);
    exit;
```

I've just finished some courses so I'm a beginner and I don't know that much about this.

Comment: `echo $sql` see if that looks right

Comment: you should learn to use prepared statements instead of concatenating variables.

Comment: Can’t speak to what we don’t know... what is the output of reset_visits($page)?  Is your script then being executed? How is $page being populated?  Does $page[‘id’] have a value?  Is it the correct value?  Work on answering these, and you’ll probably fix it yourself; your basic plan seems sound.